# Clone form fields and maintain jquery functionality

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I have a form that I would like to allow users to be able to add fiields to.  The fields are a section of the form consisting of 8-9 fields that should appear after the fields they are duplicating.  Below should give you some Idea of what I'm looking at.

```
<div class="fields">
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    <input type="text" name="field3">
    <input type="text" name="field4">
</div>
```

So basically what I'm looking to do is clone the entire "fields" div and have it appear after the one that was cloned.

In addition, I have some jquery that uses slideUp and slideDown to reveal options based on the users selections.  I have it set up in a manner that allows two of these "fields" divs to coexist and still function.  My only question with regards to that is whether I would need to do something special to make it function on the cloned div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.fields').clone().insertAfter('.fields');
```

If you want any event handlers in the elements to be cloned as well, then you should set the *withDataAndEvents* parameter to true in the `clone` call.

```
$('.fields').clone(true).insertAfter('.fields');
```

If you're calling something like `$('.fields').slideDown()` to show the fields in response to a button click, that slide will apply to both the original and the cloned fields.

If you only want the slide to apply to one of the divs, say the first one, you could so something like `$('.fields').eq(0).slideDown()`.

Comment: This words to an extent, but after the first time it appends 3, then 6, ect.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: `$('.fields:first').clone(true).insertAfter('.fields:last');` That selects the first fields div, clones it and inserts it after the last div. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the duplicating problem by adding this

```
$('.fields').clone(true).attr("class","cloned").insertAfter('.fields');
```

Thanks for the help